# How to convert a pair of tuples into a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following data set:

```
data=[(('a','b','c'),('x','y','z'))]
```

How can I convert this into dictionary such that there is mapping as shown below:

```
d={'a':'x','b':'y','c':'z'}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since we're playing code golf :)

```
dict(zip(*data[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `zip` the two `tuple` and operate using `dict`.

```
In [189]: dict(zip(data[0][0], data[0][1]))
Out[189]: {'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'z'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data=[(('a','b','c'),('x','y','z'))]
dictVal = {}

for key, val in zip(data[0][0], data[0][1]):
   dictVal[key] = val
```

Comment: Consider adding a little explanation to go along with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with a dictionary comprehension.

```
d = {key:value for key in data[0][0] for value in data[0][1]}
```

You can use dictionary comprehensions like this with multiple variables and for loops to make a dictionary from two different iterables.